# how to modify xml tag specific value in java?

Tags: java, xml, edit

i am new to work on xml.i have used an xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
      - <root>
      - <key>
           <Question>Is the color of the car</Question> 
           <Ans>black?</Ans> 
       </key>
     - <key>
           <Question>Is the color of the car</Question> 
           <Ans>black?</Ans> 
       </key>
     - <key>
           <Question>Is the news paper</Question> 
           <Ans>wallstreet?</Ans> 
      </key>
    - <key>
          <Question>fragrance odor</Question> 
          <Ans>Lavendor?</Ans> 
     </key>
   - <key>
          <Question>Is the baggage collector available</Question> 
         <Ans /> 
     </key>
  </root>
```

from the above xml i would like to change only

```
             <Ans>wallstreet?</Ans> as <Ans>WonderWorld</Ans>.
```

how can i change wallstreet? as WonderWorld? through my java application.

i have written java method as shown below:

```
  public void modifyNodeval(){
 try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(path));
        Node nodes1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(int j=0;j<nodes1.getLength();j++)
        {
            //Get the staff element by tag name directly
            Node nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("key").item(j);
            //loop the staff child node
            NodeList list = nodes.getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i != list.getLength(); ++i)
            {
                Node child = list.item(i);

               if (child.getNodeName().equals("Ans")) {

                   child.getFirstChild().setNodeValue("WonderWorld") ;
                   System.out.println("tag val modified success fuly");
               }

           }
       }
       TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
       DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(path);
       transformer.transform(source, result);
   }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

by using above code i am able to change the all  tag text as wonder world but my intention is i want change only wallstreet? as WonderWorld.

any body please help me.....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code to show us? Also, if accept more answers, people here will be more helpful.

Comment: @forty-two check with my java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

`if (child.getNodeName().equals("Ans") && child.getTextContent().equals("wallstreet?"))`

as your if condition.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend XPath to select exactly what you want to edit with a lot less code:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Element e = (Element) xpath.evaluate("//Ans[. = 'wallstreet']", document, XPathConstant.NODE);
if (e != null)
  e.setTextContent("Wonderland");
```

Comment: if i want change the <Ans>black?</Ans> and <Ans>wallstreet?</Ans> at a time then how?

Comment: Well, you cannot change both at the same time. Just repeat with another expression, or refactor into a method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if the value of the node is "wallstreet?" - so it simply changes every first child node.

```
String str = child.getFirstChild( ).getNodeValue( );
if ( "wallstreet?".compareTo( str ) == 0 )
{
    child.getFirstChild( ).setNodeValue( "WonderWorld" );
    System.out.println( "tag val modified success fuly" );
}
```