# How to edit a xsl tag attribute file from Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a xsl file, used as template,which i need to modify during runtime. I need to modify attribute value of a tag. Is there a way i can do it via JAVA code? I know the location of my template xsl file.

For instance:

Sample xsl template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0"
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
<xsl:template match="Sample">   
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY >
<APPLET ARCHIVE="http://localhost:500/abc.jar" CODE="test.class" NAME="Apps" ></APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here i need to modify the APPLET tag, where i need to set the ARCHIVE value at runtime , say to be `"http://localhost:800/xyz.jar"`

Can i read this xsl file from Java somwhow and modify the atrribute for applet tag?

Comment: Since xsl is just xml, you can edit it as any xml in java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646607/how-to-modify-xml-tag-specific-value-in-java

Comment: @Piro Editing the stylesheet dynamically is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XSL paramteter to transfer the value

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
>
  <xsl:param name="archive" select="''" />

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Sample">   
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <applet archive="{$archive}" code="test.class" name="Apps" />
      </body>
     </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Read up on how to pass XSL parameters in your XSLT engine. Saxon would use the [`XsltTransformer.SetParameter` method](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.0/dotnetdoc/Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer.SetParameter.html), other engines work similarly.

By the way, ALL UPPERCASE HTML was last used in the 90's.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak , will try this approach.