# How to update xml files in java

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml file call data.xml like the code below. The project can run from client side no problem and it can read the xml file. The problem I have now is I I want to write a function that can update the startdate and enddate. I have no idea how to get start. Help will be appreciated.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<data>
       <username>admin</username>
       <password>12345</password>
       <interval>1</interval>
       <timeout>90</timeout>
       <startdate>01/01/2013</startdate>
       <enddate>06/01/2013</enddate>
       <ttime>1110</ttime>
    </data>
```

my main.java

```
    public class main
    {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          Calendar cal2 =null;

    try {   

              //read the xml      
              File data = new File("data.xml");  
              DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();         
              DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();           
              Document doc = dBuilder.parse(data);         
              doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {     
              Node node = nodes.item(i);           
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {     
                    Element element = (Element) node;   
                    username = getValue("username", element);
                    startdate = getValue("startdate", element);
                    enddate = getValue("enddate", element);
                  }
       }


  date = startdate; 
  Date date_int = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date); 
  cal2 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
 cal2.setTime(date_int); 


     //loop the child node to update the initial date
              for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {    
                  Node node = nodes.item(i);           
                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {     
                        Element element = (Element) node;

                        setValue("startdate", element , date_int.toString());
                  }
              }

            //write the content in xml file
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("data.xml"));
                transformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (Exception ex) {    
          log.error(ex.getMessage());       
          ex.printStackTrace();       
        }
    }


      private static void setValue(String tag, Element element , String input) {  
            NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();   
            Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0); 
            node.setTextContent(input);

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124239/how-to-update-xml-using-xpath-and-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646607/how-to-modify-xml-tag-specific-value-in-java

Comment: At least show your code what have you tried

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Start by loading the XML file...

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = b.parse(new File("Data.xml"));
```

Now, there are a few ways to do this, but simply, you can use the xpath API to find the nodes you want and update their content

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Node startDateNode = (Node) xPath.compile("/data/startdate").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
startDateNode.setTextContent("29/07/2015");

xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Node endDateNode = (Node) xPath.compile("/data/enddate").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
endDateNode.setTextContent("29/07/2015");
```

Then save the `Document` back to the file...

```
Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("Data.xml"));
tf.transform(domSource, sr);
```

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer, thank you for your answer, I have got the xml part working. Now what if I want to update the startdate's month increase by one such as 29/07/2015, 29/8/2015, 20/10/2015 .... something like this, how should I do that? Should I create a method to do it? Can you provide an example?

Comment: You could simply use Java 8's Time API which has simple to use manipulation, parsing and formatting

Comment: Will you be able to provide an example?

Comment: Something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255811/start-date-and-end-date-between-two-dates/25255894#25255894)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your respond, now I have updated my answer, how will you apply that into my code? I use Dom Parser instead of XPath. Thanks

Comment: @gaurav Without having read the docs, I would say, no, it's probably not or at least, you shouldn't assume it so

Answer (score 9):

Firstly there is an error in your XML you have extra `<data>` tag . I have removed it. Now you have two options you could either use `SAX` or `DOM`. I would suggest `DOM` reason being that you can read full XML using `DOM` and for a small piece of XML like this it's better choice.

Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ModifyXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            String filepath = "file.xml";
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

            // Get the root element
            Node data= doc.getFirstChild();

            Node startdate = doc.getElementsByTagName("startdate").item(0);

            // I am not doing any thing with it just for showing you
            String currentStartdate = startdate.getNodeValue();

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            startdate.setTextContent(df.format(today));

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Corrected XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <username>admin</username>
   <password>12345</password>
   <interval>1</interval>
   <timeout>90</timeout>
   <startdate>29/07/2015</startdate>
   <enddate>06/01/2013</enddate>
   <ttime>1110</ttime>
</data>
```

Comment: Hi Shahzeb, thank you for your answer, I have got the xml part working. Now what if I want to update the startdate's month increase by one such as 29/07/2015, 29/8/2015, 20/10/2015 .... something like this, how should I do that? Should I create a method to do it?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: My Answer already does that . please try out the code that I have given here .

Comment: In my answer I am only updating `startdate` you can add `enddate`

Comment: @gaurav not by default but you can put it in threadsafe methods

Answer (score 2):

This an example which i have tried for updating the xml files.

```
        String filepath="Test.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
        Node company = doc.getFirstChild();

        /**
         * Get the param from xml and set value
         */
        Node search = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter").item(0);
        NamedNodeMap attr = search.getAttributes();
        Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("value");
        nodeAttr.setTextContent(param);

        /**
         * write it back to the xml
         */
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Done");
```

Following is the XML file i have used:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="Testing" parallel="false">
    <parameter name="Search" value="param1"></parameter>
     <test name="TestParams" preserve-order="true">
       <classes>
         <class name="uiscreen.TestingParam"/>
       </classes>
     </test> <!-- Test -->
   </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can read xml to the linked hash map and regenerate xml after modification. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1JLX)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>"
        + "<data>"
        + "       <username>admin</username>"
        + "       <password>12345</password>"
        + "       <interval>1</interval>"
        + "       <timeout>90</timeout>"
        + "       <startdate>01/01/2013</startdate>"
        + "       <enddate>06/01/2013</enddate>"
        + "       <ttime>1110</ttime>"
        + "    </data>";  
        java.util.Map<String, Object> object = U.fromXmlMap(xml);
        U.set(object, "data.startdate", "02/02/2013");
        U.set(object, "data.enddate", "07/02/2013");
        System.out.println(U.toXml(object)); 
    }
}

// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
// <data>
//   <username>admin</username>
//   <password>12345</password>
//   <interval>1</interval>
//   <timeout>90</timeout>
//   <startdate>02/02/2013</startdate>
//   <enddate>07/02/2013</enddate>
//   <ttime>1110</ttime>
// </data>
```