# How to update XML file in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and I would like to update the dates to existing xml file but not sure ho to do it lets say the file is File.xml
and I need to change the date in:

So I need to update the start and end date.
Thanks

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693670/how-to-update-xml-files-in-java/31693809#31693809)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion there will be to go through this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/) or use [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html) library to manipulate your xml file.

XStream is super easy.

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("file.xml")
Data newJoe = (Data)xstream.fromXML(reader);
```

You need to create `Data` class that need correspond to xml document that you have.