# Parsing a file containing a list of xmls and modifying the same

Tags: java, xml

I have a file which contains a list of xmls , one on each line. When I try to parse this file using the code given here:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

I get parsing error when my file looks like this(multiple xmls, say File1)-

```
<T1>  
    <T2>    
        <T4>        
            <T3>TEST</T3>   
        </T4>  
    </T2>   
    <T5>    
        <TID>NEwid:0</TID>  
    </T5> 
</T1>
<T1>  
    <T2>    
        <T4>        
            <T3>TEST</T3>   
        </T4>  
    </T2>   
    <T5>    
        <TID>NEwid:1</TID>  
    </T5> 
</T1>
```

However, following file parses successfully(single xml, say File2)

```
<T1>  
    <T2>    
        <T4>        
            <T3>TEST</T3>   
        </T4>  
    </T2>   
    <T5>    
        <TID>NEwid:0</TID>  
    </T5> 
</T1>
```

My requirement is that I need to replace the value of  tag in each of the xmls which will be present in a single file(the file format will be like File1  ).Am not sure if File1 is even a proper xml , but that is how the file is like.
I am able to replace the value of  when I place only one xml in a file .
(Have used the best answer stated here: [How to update xml files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693670/how-to-update-xml-files-in-java))

Comment: A file that "contains a list of xmls [sic]" is not XML; an XML document must have a single root element.

Comment: @kjhughes  So reading the file , using regex and replacing the tag value, writing back to file is my only option then?

Comment: See [**How to parse invalid XML?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

Comment: Is there any way a single file to contain multiple xml using some xml end character or something?

Comment: An XML document must have a single root element; asking again won't change the answer.